# Querying data from different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using a query like this on my postgres database:

```
SELECT TableA.id FROM TableA , TableB WHERE TableA.id = 100;
```

Each TableA.id is unique (it's an autoincrement), I am getting more than 1 result. Am I missing something in here?

Answer (score 7):

You need a join:

```
SELECT TableA.ID from TableA
INNER JOIN TableB 
ON TableB.TableAID = TableA.ID 
WHERE TableA.ID = 100
```

Answer (score 6):

You're doing a cross-join - effectively every row in TableB against the single row in TableA. If you select something from TableB as well, this will be more obvious :) The fact that you don't currently select anything from TableB doesn't stop the (TableA, TableB) pairs from being the result of the join, before the projection.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting one row from `TableA` but all rows from `TableB`.  Perhaps you meant:

```
SELECT TableA.id FROM TableA, TableB WHERE TableA.id=TableB.id AND TableA.id = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

which is the relation between TableA and TableB?

you might need to do something like this

Where TableA.id = 100
And TableB.TableA_Id = TableA.id

Answer (score 0):

You need a join before the where clause:

```
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.Id
```